# show that $X_n$ convergences almost surely and in $L^2$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales

\begin{array}{l}{\text { let } \theta \in]0,1[,\left\{\epsilon_{n}, n \geq 1\right\} \text { a sequence of Bernoulli r.v's }} \\ {\qquad X_{n+1}=\theta X_{n}+(1-\theta) \epsilon_{n+1}, \quad n \geq 0}\end{array}

Question : show that $X_n$ convergences almost surely and in $L^2$

I could show that $0 < X_n < 1$ and that $X_n$ is a martingale but I don't know what to do next.

help me please.

Comment: A martingale which is bounded in $L^2$ converges almost surely and in $L^2$, this is a well known theorem.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the answer, does this theroem have a name so I can look it up ?

Comment: The main statement is the "martingale convergence theorem" which says that a supermartingale which is bounded in $L^1$ converges almost surely. (not necessary convergent in $L^1$ though). You should start from it. Then there is a stronger version which says that a martingale which is bounded in $L^2$ also converges in $L^2$. (and obviously converges almost surely by the martingale convergence theorem)

Answer (score 2):

An $\mathbb L^2$-bounded martingale is Uniformly Integrable by Hölder inequality, therefore **Doob's Convergence Theorem** applies.

Here, the martingale is even bounded in $\mathbb L^\infty\subset\mathbb L^2$.